Cut a TIFF in QGIS software
I'd like to cut a TIFF.
I create a shp (polygon) and I try make a cut but things don't work:
Warning 1: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 113707.074431456 -498036.38907591888
ERROR 1: Cutline polygon is invalid.
Processo retornou código de erro 1
Execution completed in 0.26 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/andre/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_RyfHQk/e3626590881342cb8a98dae854e5a257/OUTPUT.tif'}

Carregando camada resultante
As seguintes camadas não foram geradas corretamente.
• C:/Users/andre/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_RyfHQk/e3626590881342cb8a98dae854e5a257/OUTPUT.tif
Você pode verificar o 'Painel de Registro de Mensagens' na janela principal do QGIS para encontrar mais informações sobre a realização do algoritmo.


The error message is telling you that the cut polygon is invalid due to a self-intersection. Try running Fix Geometries on your polygon layer.

(Fix Geometries)
